# Table text hover and link color

Tags: html, css, css-selectors, css-specificity

I have html table and layout for it (something like that, also i use haml+sass):

```
.zebra{
 .zebra-stripe{
  &.zebra1{
  a{
    color: red;
  }
  a:hover{
    color: blue;
  }
 }
}
```

my htm table has class zebra, and tr has class .zebra-stripe .zebra1

but there i have link with other style (like button)  and this link has own height with background,  but color is setted to orange on hover,

```
.details-link{
  width: 70px;
  margin: 2px;
}
.details-link:hover{
  color: orange;
}
```

but when my mouse is over this link it's color is not orange, but blue as setted for table.... what is wrong?

How to set link hover text color to orange (i setted it, but it is not viewing properly)....

If something is not clear write me in comments...

Comment: @Daniel Imms: Tags are meant to describe the question, not the answers. Since it isn't immediately obvious from the question that the problem lies in selector specificity it's not appropriate to force the tags into the question. It is also not necessary to fill in all 5 tags on every question - tags like [hover] aren't very effective here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You problem is the specificity of the selectors you're using, `.zebra .zebra-stripe.zebra1 a:hover` is more specific than `.details-link:hover`. Try the following instead to make your selector more specific:

```
.zebra .zebra-stripe.zebra1 a.details-link:hover {
    color: orange;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try out this:

```
a.details-link:hover{
    color: orange;
}
```